# Does stopping a BizTalk host instance also stop the Applications that run under it?

Tags: biztalk

Does stopping a BizTalk host instance also stop the Applications that run under it?

Or, what is the difference between stopping a host instance and stopping the applications under it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, host instances and applications are completely independent. You can stop a host instance and the application will remain in the started state. You can stop an application and the host instance will remain in the running state.

To understand the difference between stopping a host instance and stopping an application you first need to understand what these things are.

Basically, you need to think of your application as a set of assemblies plus some runtime configuration, and a set of logical subscriptions.

When you "start" an application up there are actually two steps which happen.

1. The parts of your application which need to receive messages (orchestrations and send ports) are *enlisted*. This ensures that an internal queue exists to receive the messages. Note that the application is not yet started, but it can receive and queue messages for processing later.
2. Then when you *start* the application the various parts of your application are able to process the messages.

The host instance is basically a windows service.

When you stop the host instance, all you are really doing is stopping the underlying windows service which runs the host instance. This means that all the assemblies which contain your application artifacts are unloaded, and the application will obviously stop processing. This is despite the fact that the application is still in the *started* state.

When you start the host instance again it loads your application assemblies back into memory and will be able to continue processing new messages. Messages which were being processed when the host instance was stopped may be in a state called *suspended*, but if they are can be manually resumed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you application run only on that host instance (meaning: application will stop to process messages). However internals of why it stopped processing is quite different. See explanation below and in **hugh jadick**'s answer.

Stopping [host instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560673%28BTS.20%29.aspx) for specified [host type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578695%28BTS.20%29.aspx) will stop execution of all artifacts (adapter handlers, receive locations, pipelines, orchestrations, etc.) that run on specified host. Application is a logical group of artifacts which can run on single or multiple host instances. Multiple applications can run on a single host instance, and vice versa. So, stopping an app is just shutdown of execution of artifacts, while stopping host instance is shutdown of physical instance there app artifacts are executing.

Comment: @hugh I've tried to express same meaning, yet my language was not good enough. I'll correct my answer to clarify first paragraph.